# Is there a way with Laravel, to forget a session variable in the view?

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-blade

I'm talking about something like

```
<?php unset( session('error_message') ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php unset( $_SESSION['error_message'] ); ?>
```

or

```
@\Session::forget('error_message');
```

I'd need it, in order to forget  the 'error_message' just after including the html to show the user that his operation wasn't (or was) successful. Like so:

```
@if(\Session::has('error_message'))
    <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
        @include('partials.missatgeError')
    </div>

    <!-- FORGET HERE -->

@endif

@if(\Session::has('success_message'))
    <div class="container-fluid mt-4">
        @include('partials.missatgeCorrecte')
    </div>

    <!-- FORGET HERE -->

@endif
```

Comment: did you try `Session::forget('error_message')`. It should work fine.

Comment: This one seems to work, doesn't throw any errors, but the html that shows the alert is always included, it is like Session::forget('error_message') isn't actually removing it.